# how can i display the data that is present inside BufferReader which is running inside the doInBackground of AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, sockets

The below code shows how does the data sent to server and Received from there

```
public class SendMessage extends AsyncTask<String,String, String> {

    private Exception exception;
    String mes;

    protected String doInBackground(String... params){

            try{

                //socket creation
                Socket socket= new Socket("192.168.0.115",8888);

                //send activity to server
                PrintWriter outToServer = new PrintWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(
                                socket.getOutputStream()));

                //printing the received data
                outToServer.print(params[0]);

                //send the data to server and clear the output stream
                outToServer.flush();

                //Create the input stream to receive data
                DataInputStream dis2 = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                //create the input stream reader to read the data
                InputStreamReader disR2 = new InputStreamReader(dis2);

                //Create the buffer reader to store the data
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(disR2);





            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        return  null;

    }
```

How can i Display the data that is present inside the AsyncTask.
 used  //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,br,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
but i am not able to display.

Comment: For Print BufferedReader data you need to pass this in onPost() method and print there. doInBackground() method will never print anything directly.

Comment: @GovindRathod Tried to use onPost() method  not  able to do it can u plz help me to solve this problem

Comment: @viswas please refer and try my Answer please appreciate it with upVote. if it would be beneficial to you. Require any help, please revert

Comment: @GovindRathod ok sir thank you

Answer (score 0):

Look below you have to pass your return type as BufferedReader in AsyncTask, then you can get this in your onPost() method

```
public class SendMessage extends AsyncTask<String,String, BufferedReader  > {

    private Exception exception;
    String mes;

    protected BufferedReader doInBackground(String... params){

            try{

                //socket creation
                Socket socket= new Socket("192.168.0.115",8888);

                //send activity to server
                PrintWriter outToServer = new PrintWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(
                                socket.getOutputStream()));

                //printing the received data
                outToServer.print(params[0]);

                //send the data to server and clear the output stream
                outToServer.flush();

                //Create the input stream to receive data
                DataInputStream dis2 = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                //create the input stream reader to read the data
                InputStreamReader disR2 = new InputStreamReader(dis2);

                //Create the buffer reader to store the data
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(disR2);





            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return  br;
    }


protected void onPostExecute(BufferedReader result) {
        // process with your BufferedReader here
     }
```

Comment: @vishwas could you check this ? you have to change Return Type of doInBackground method

Comment: Sir i was able to solve this problem. Thank you for helping me sir.